# what's the correct way to destroy a javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I'm not too familiar with object orientated Javascript but lets say I have a function which I  *instantiated*.. ?

Is that the correct terminology?

The function contains an `XMLHttpRequest` with an attached event listener, what would be the correct way to dispose the function?

```
function foo() {
    var self = this;
    self.message = "received response";
    self.url = 'someUrl';
    self.req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    self.req.open("POST", self.url, true);
    self.req.onload = function () {
        console.log(self.message); // Unable to get property 'message' of 
        // undefined or null reference
    };
    self.req.send();
    self = null;
}

var foo = new foo();
```

I realize this is not how I should abort an `XMLHttpRequest` but its just an example, the question is how should I cleanly destroy a function and all that it spawned or created?

***Edit***

To Clarify, my confusion is with `self.req.onload` and how it can even exist when `self` = `null`? my thought would be that `self.req` no longer exists and therefore its events too but this is obviously not the case

Comment: The symbol "self" is not defined in your code.

Comment: just let it go out of scope - you could set it to a different value.

Comment: @Pointy sorry, edited

Comment: I don't see a reason why `foo` should be a constructor function. Just make a it a "normal" function and don't use `this`/`self`.

Comment: Real programmers use a magnetic needle and a steady hand...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol as far as i can tell you're implying that I'm over complicating things? In my live code the function contains many variables and event listeners, which would be nice to destroy in a single hit. I just don't know if its possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, JavaScript functions are objects, and therefore they are *instantiated*. Function declarations create a function when the scope is entered, function expressions do when they are evaluated.

However, in JavaScript you don't *dispose* objects. You just let them go out of scope (remove all references to them), and the garbage collector will take care of them. For example, when you `foo.req.abort()` the request, or the response arrives, and `foo.req.onload` is no longer accessible, then your listener function will be garbage collected.

Comment: I think the OP was referring to the `var foo = new foo();` when he said "instantiated".

Comment: @FelixKling: Oh - hm - but then the question doesn't make much sense? Not sure what the OP wants to do.

Comment: @Bergi what I don't understand, is why `console.log(self.message);` even happens when `self` is set to `null`? How can `self.req.onload` still exist?

Comment: @andrew `self.req.onload` doesn't exist, however the callback that it created does.

Comment: The `foo` object, the `XMLHttpRequest` object and the handler function do exist separately from each other. By setting `self=null`, you've just destroyed the `self` variable, making it impossible to access the `foo` object via `self` in that scope. If you didn't assign the result of calling `new Foo()` to `foo`, setting `self=null` would have (implicitly) "destroyed" the object (including its `message`, `url`, `req` properties) and made it available for garbage collection. The request object would *still* exist, it only is no more accessible via `self.req` then.

Answer (score 1):

I would write you example like this:

```
function foo () {
  var message = "received response";
  var url = 'someUrl';
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("POST", url, true);
  req.onload = function () {
    console.log(message);
  };
  req.send();
}

// No need to instantiate foo, just call it when you want to make your request
// No need for foo to "remember" variables.

foo();
```